# Posting desired message on facebook using api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am trying to post a message through apis on facebook wall. The problem is it appears differently when i post via api then when i directly paste a link as facebook status. I am not sure if i am doing something wrong. Please advise.

The link i want to post as an example is http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/blood/2415012_26-May-2012

The code i am using is something like:

```
FacebookType publishMessageResponse =                             facebookClient.publish("me/feed", FacebookType.class,
Parameter.with("name", "Click here to Register as a Blood Donor"),
Parameter.with("picture", "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/blood/2415012_26-May-2012"),
Parameter.with("link", "http://links.sakshum.org/RegisterBloodDonor"),
Parameter.with("description", "Sakshum is a not for profit organization working in the field of child education and building an effective blood donor pool."));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you paste directly Facebook tries to infer the meta OG tags.

See the debugger for more information http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fcommondatastorage.googleapis.com%2Fblood%2F2415012_26-May-2012

> Inferred Property:    The 'og:url' property should be explicitly
> provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property:    The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even
> if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property:    The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a
> value can be inferred from other tags. ... etc

Set your meta tags in the `<head>` section of the url and you wouldn't have to set it.

And in your `<head>`

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/blood/2415012_26-May-2012">
<meta property="og:title" content="Click here to Register as a Blood Donor">
<meta property="og:description" content="Sakshum is a not for profit organization working in the field of child education and building an effective blood donor pool.">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://YOURURL.COM/LINKTOIMG.jpg">
```

For more information on `feed` see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Comment: so in this case what should i set as meta tag to appear the contents of the link ?

Comment: @Vik Your html page has a section called <head> http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp

Comment: oh ok so you mean while creating that page i set this stuff?

Comment: @vik If you own the page, yes, if not you must use as you did above with the `feed` method

Comment: you said something different here. What do you mean by "you did above with the feed method " ? Do u mean i can do in the rest api call this meta data setting? if yes then what would be the syntax?

Comment: @Vik You wrote the code in your question to create a name for a link, show a picture and provide a description. You cannot force meta information via `feed`, the only way to add meta information is to actually add it to the html in the page.

Comment: i tried as you suggested. See the modified html at http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/blood/152003_11-Jul-2012 but through api it still does not print the description

Comment: @Vik that gives a HTTP 206 to something else commondatastorage.googleapis.com/blood/2415012_26-May-2012 so it wouldn't work. The og tags must be on the final url. As long at the final url contains the meta you can use the API call.